# Python 3 control multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write function using Python multiprocessing that i can control it  and pass "command" to cleanly terminate the process.
I looked for few examples and tried it out ,but didn't seems to work fro me
So basically i need to to run separate process function code that doing some  while loop action
and when needed stop it by passing somehow command and exit
Please advice
Thanks

> example 1

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def start_process(queue):
  while True:
    try:
        m = queue.get()
        if m == 'exit':
            print ('cleaning up worker...')
            # add here your cleaning up code
            break
        else:
            print (m)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ('ignore CTRL-C from worker')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  queue = Queue()

  process = Process(target=start_process, args=(queue,))
  process.start()

  queue.put(12)

  try:
    process.join()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ('wait for worker to cleanup...')
    queue.put('exit')
    process.join()
```

> example 2

```
import multiprocessing
    import time

    class MyProcess(multiprocessing.Process):

        def __init__(self, ):
            multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
            self.exit = multiprocessing.Event()

        def run(self):
            while not self.exit.is_set():
                pass
            print ("You exited!")

        def shutdown(self):
            print ("Shutdown initiated")
            self.exit.set()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        process = MyProcess()
        process.start()
        print ("Waiting for a while")
        time.sleep(3)
        process.shutdown()
        time.sleep(3)
        print ("Child process state: %d" % process.is_alive())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both examples works fine for me - perhaps you're misunderstanding how they should work?

in the first example, when the main thread runs, it starts the child and sends 12.  then it waits to join the child.  at that point everything is stalled because the child is waiting for 'exit'.  but if you then hit ctrl-C the 'exit' is sent, the child exits, and the second join is successful:

```
> python3.3 example1.py                                                    
12                                                                              
^Cignore CTRL-C from worker                                                     
wait for worker to cleanup...                                                   
cleaning up worker...                                                           
>
```

if you just want the parent to send 'exit' and then for everything to end, use:

```
def start_process(queue):                                                       
  while True:                                                                   
    try:                                                                        
        m = queue.get()                                                         
        if m == 'exit':                                                         
            print ('cleaning up worker...')                                     
            # add here your cleaning up code
            break
        else:
            print (m)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ('ignore CTRL-C from worker')
  print('goodbye cruel world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  queue = Queue()

  process = Process(target=start_process, args=(queue,))
  process.start()

  queue.put(12)
  print ('sending exit')
  queue.put('exit')
  process.join()
```

which gives:

```
> python3.3 my-example.py 
sending exit
12
cleaning up worker...
goodbye cruel world
>
```

your second example also works (with the indentation fixed):

```
> python3.3 example2.py 
Waiting for a while
Shutdown initiated
You exited!
Child process state: 0
>
```

(just wait a little).  not sure what else you could have expected here.